# watchOS2 app maximum memory usage

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchos-2, watchos

My current `watchOS2` app fetches 10 huge dictionaries from the iPhone via `watchConnectivity`. It takes about 10 seconds and 17 mb of memory on the simulator. When it comes to the real device - the app just quits when the exchange of data starts.

Is there any max limit of RAM for a single `watchOS2` app ?

Thank you

Comment: [WCSession documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WCSession) has some error codes such as `PayloadTooLarge` that implies there is a hard limit to the amount of data that can be sent via WatchConnectivity, in addition to any memory/storage constraints on the device itself (see the `InsufficientSpace` error code). Documentation does not provide any actual numbers for these limits though.

Comment: Might want to see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35076706/795339) discussion too, it identifies some limits, and also note that you may have better luck using the file transfer methods of WCSession rather than the sendMessage/userInfo/applicationContext methods. Overall though, I would suggest doing everything you can to reduce the amount of data you are sending to the watch, as excessive data transfer will degrade the user experience and reliability even if you get around the crashing.